# Firebase update the retrieved document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in my Firebase with documents, where I retrieve data in the following way:

```
 self.db.collection("ustas").order(by: "stats").limit(to: 20).getDocuments() { (querysnapshot,err) in
         for document in querysnapshot!.documents {
         }
}
```

I want to perform some actions, but after that, I want to update the `impressions+=1`, for each document. Is it possible to dynamically do it?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your database structure?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please edit the question to explain what part of this are you having problems with. Do you have code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the document, call a function as in the example below from viewDidLoad()

```
func updateDocumentStats() {
    let docRef = self.db.collection("ustas").document("YourDocumentId")

    docRef.updateData([
        "impressions": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
    ])
}
```